# Task timed out when connecting documentdb through pymongo in aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to fetch my bookings collection from AWS Document db cluster. I've maintained the credentials using AWS Secret Manager and passing them to connect. However, it gives me a Task Timed Out Error of 900 seconds. (I increased the time limit to 15 mins since it gave the same error with  lesser duration)

The error is as such:

> {
> "errorMessage": "2021-08-19T09:05:22.872Z a96e95cb-4c42-4880-b339-9cb29e83c1ec Task timed out after 900.10 seconds"
> }

Code snippet:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    
    db = create_mongo_connection()
    print(db)
    print("aaaaa")                    # this gets printed -- debugging 
    bookings = db.bookings.find({})   # bookings collection not fetched
    print("bbbbb")                    # this does not get printed -- debugging 

#configuration settings maintained in environment variables 
mongoconfig = os.environ['mongoconfig']

def create_mongo_connection():
    try :
        secretsmanager = get_secret()
        SecretString = json.loads(secretsmanager)
        username = SecretString['username']
        password = SecretString['password']
        host = SecretString['host']
        port = SecretString['port']
        mongoclient = MongoClient(host, port, username=username, password=password, 
        authSource='admin',  ssl_ca_certs='rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem',retryWrites='false')
        dbname = mongoconfig['db_name']
        print(dbname)
        return mongoclient[dbname]
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception : ", e, "\nTraceback : ", format_exc())
```

Comment: The the AWS Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is there a particular reason _why_ it is connected to a VPC? If not, then disconnect it and try again.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein DIsconnecting VPC works ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API endpoints for the Secrets Manager live on the Internet. It sounds like the Lambda function is **not able to access the Internet**.

When an AWS Lambda function is **connected to a VPC**, it can access resources in the VPC. However, to access the Internet:

- The **Lambda function** must be in a private subnet, *and*
- A **NAT Gateway** must be in a public subnet

If the Lambda function does *not* require access to resources in the VPC, then simply **disconnect the Lambda function from the VPC** and it will receive Internet access automatically.

There is another option, which is to [Use Secrets Manager with VPC endpoints - AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html), which creates a tunnel between a VPC and the Secrets Manager.